# Generics erasure and legacy code

Tags: java, generics

In many books is said that the reason for which Java's generic use erasure is
to have compatibility with legacy code.

Ok, very good but can anyone show me some simple examples where some
generic code interact with old legacy code and vice-versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example that wouldn't be possible without *type erasure*:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> newList = legacyMethod();

    for (String s : newList) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

public static List legacyMethod() {
    List oldList = new ArrayList();
    oldList.add("a");
    oldList.add("b");
    oldList.add("c");
    return oldList;
}
```

Comment: It's not a very good example, having the old and the new in the same method.

Answer (score 3):

Having compatibility with the legacy code means that it should be able to run on the new version of JVM without compilation. Let's say you are having some legacy library without source code. This ensures that you'll be able to run it on Java 5. Your new code will be able to call legacy code without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Run old code on a current JRE and the uses of the likes of `List` will be old code using new. Methods suck as `Collections.sort` will be new code calling back to old.

Answer (score 0):

Take any old Java library which hasn't been ported to Java 5, yet. You'll find plenty of places where the old code returns or accepts `List`. Without erasure, you couldn't use generics in your code (to make your life more simple) and pass your lists as parameters to the framework without (shallow) copying the whole thing - `List` and `List<String>` would be as different as `String` and `File`.

In a similar fashion, when the library returns a list, you'd either have to use the pre-5 syntax with an iterator to process it or copy the basic list into a generified one.

There would be way to work around that. Sun could have made `List` equal to `List<Object>` or, God forbid, `List<?>`. But that would have introduced even more subtle problems. So they decided to go the way of least resistance and use the generic information (mostly) during compilation.